# PhantomJS + CasperJS click() won't work if anything else is performed in same function

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to send input to a website, but also have the user confirm whether they want to continue from the console, and then proceed if confirmation is given. However I'm running into an issue with the click function.

```
casper.then(function(){
        this.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAllSvr');
        });
```

Works but...

```
casper.then(function(){

    var confirmation = system.stdin.readLine();
    if(confirmation == 'y'){
        this.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAllSvr');
        this.capture('test7.png');
        this.echo('success');
    }   
    this.exit();
});
```

this does not. It feels like if anything besides the click function is used inside casper.then() it doesn't fire correctly at all.

```
var system = require('system');
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').selectXPath;
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});
casper.start();
casper.thenOpen('https://someurl.com', function(){
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.click('#button1');
});

casper.then(function(){
    lastname = casper.evaluate(function () {
    return   __utils__.getElementByXPath('//form[@id=\'aspnetForm\']//tbody/tr[2]/td[4]').innerHTML;
    });
    system.stdout.write('\nReset password for this user? Y/N \n');
    var confirmation = system.stdin.readLine();
    if(confirmation == 'y'){        
    this.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSAllSvr');
            this.echo('success');
    }
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Is the "this.echo('success');" happening?

Comment: Yes the 'this.echo('success'); is happening

Comment: Don't know the problem maybe move "this.exit()" into its own "caper.then(..".